# How to adjust font size of text in a UIButton to fit the width programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, resize, xcode6

I am trying to set the text in my `UIButton` programmatically, but the text becomes abbreviated when displayed in the button. Is there a way to  adjust the font size of the text in the button to fit the width, through code? I have checked other questions, but the answers do not solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this `button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this line for button object:

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work with the titleLabel you can use UILabel's adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

and then use UILabel's minimumScaleFactor to set a minimum:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/minimumScaleFactor