# UIButton not Changing Length in Different Language

Tags: swift, localization, uibutton

I have developed an iOS app that I have localized in both French and English. I have a UIButton in my UINavigationBar that reads `Back` in English and `Retourner`in French. My UIButton seems to just take the length from the English button as default so when the app is opened on a French device the text doesn't fit in the button.

I've tried having the UIButton read `Retourner` in my Storyboard and I can't seem to set a constraint for the length. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you can use this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135032/ios-uibutton-resize-according-to-text-length

Comment: The methods indicated there were depreciated with iOS 7. Is there a way to do this with IB?

Answer (score 1):

Try this then

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Found in: [How to adjust font size of text in a UIButton to fit the width programmatically in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561156/how-to-adjust-font-size-of-text-in-a-uibutton-to-fit-the-width-programmatically)

Comment: This makes the text fit but it does this by shrinking the text so now it fits but is hard to read. How can this be done by elongating the button?

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out theres a provided method for this!

I just set:

`backButton.sizeToFit()`

In my `viewDidLoad` and it worked like a charm.